# wikimedia Lockdown with existing Namespaces

Tags: wikimedia, lockdown

I'm using an Media Wiki for documentation. After I added a lot of Pages with Namespace for example `INTERN:My Page` or `Public:My Page` and want to restrict read access for this existend Namespaces.

I've found the Extension "Lockdown" and can use it for new, custom, Namespaces:

```
define ("NS_CUSTOM", 110);
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_CUSTOM] = "customNamespace";

$wgNamespacePermissionLockdown[NS_CUSTOM]['*'] = array('sysop');
```

If I try the same Code for my existent Namespaces the old pages aren't accessable - it seems like the pages does not exist.

Is there a way to restrict the access of existing Namespaces? Can I found the Namespace ID somewhere in the Database?

Comment: Do you use all those three lines, when you want to lock down NS_PROJECT for instance?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Lockdown documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLockdown), a single line should suffice for an already existing namespace like NS_PROJECT:

```
$wgNamespacePermissionLockdown[NS_PROJECT]['*'] = array('sysop');
```

From your question and your own answer it is not clear enough what your configuration looks like (e.g. whether you are trying to lock down multiple namespaces and maybe did some errors there). However, you should *not*

1. redefine existing namespaces
2. re-use the NS_CUSTOM definition for different namespace ids (which is a variant of 1.)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new custom Namespace

```
define ("NS_CUSTOM", 111);
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_CUSTOM] = "customNamespace";
$wgNamespacePermissionLockdown[NS_CUSTOM]['*'] = array('sysop');
```

and changed so ROWs in `page` Database Table to `page_namespace = 111`